# Return text of selected select dropdown given the value of selected select dropdown using knockout?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to grab the selected text of a dropdown menu using Knockout, however, the problem is the value that is returned with the `value` binding is the literal `value=""` of the selected option, which is just a numeric ID (which isn't very useful considering I'm trying to display the name (stored in the text), not the ID.

For example, here's my DOM structure:

```
 <select data-bind="options: siteUsers, optionsText: 'UserName', optionsValue: 'UserId', optionsCaption: 'Select...', value: addedUserId"></select>
```

I want `addedUserId` to be the literal text of the option (i.e. `UserName`, not `UserId`). How can I fetch this?

Do I have to use a computed? If so, how would I go about implementing such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Just change optionsValue to 'UserName'.

```
<select data-bind="options: siteUsers, optionsText: 'UserName', optionsValue: 'UserName', optionsCaption: 'Select...', value: addedUserId"></select>
```

Otherwise you could do a loop through the options using the ID and find the name selected.

Comment: I need the `UserId` for later if I need to interact with my database however. Could you explain the looping through, please?

Comment: Do an $.each loop on the siteUsers collection and on each pass check the UserID for the selected value.  If they match return the UserName on the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly you need something like `SelectedText` out when you select something in your drop down .

Well in this case you just need to subscribe to `value` binding which is `addedUserId`

```
self.optionstext=ko.observable(); 
self.addedUserId.subscribe(function(selVal){ //selVal is alias of `optionsValue` 

//if needed check undefined condition further
var data = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.siteUsers(),function(item){
           if(selVal === item.UserId())
           {return true;} else {return false;}
       });

if(data != [])
self.optionstext(data[0].UserName());

});
```

You can use `computed` as well but subscribe is best for performance .